# How to Multiply all values within a column with SQL like SUM()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum

Lets say I have table with 1 column like this:

```
Col A
1
2
3
4
```

If I `SUM` it, then I will get this:

```
Col A
10
```

My question is: how do I multiply Col A so I get the following?

```
Col A
24
```

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Just for fun, or school work, or real work task?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Using a combination of `ROUND`, `EXP`, `SUM` and `LOG`

```
SELECT ROUND(EXP(SUM(LOG([Col A]))),1)
FROM yourtable
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d43c8/2/0

Explanation

`LOG` returns the logarithm of col a ex. `LOG([Col A])` which returns

```
0
0.6931471805599453
1.0986122886681098
1.3862943611198906
```

Then you use `SUM` to Add them all together `SUM(LOG([Col A]))` which returns

```
3.1780538303479453
```

Then the exponential of that result is calculated using `EXP(SUM(LOG(['3.1780538303479453'])))` which returns

```
23.999999999999993
```

Then this is finally rounded using `ROUND` `ROUND(EXP(SUM(LOG('23.999999999999993'))),1)` to get `24`

---

### Extra Answers

Simple resolution to:

> An invalid floating point operation occurred.

When you have a `0` in your data

```
SELECT ROUND(EXP(SUM(LOG([Col A]))),1)
FROM yourtable
WHERE [Col A] != 0
```

If you only have `0` Then the above would give a result of `NULL`.

> When you have negative numbers in your data set.

```
SELECT (ROUND(exp(SUM(log(CASE WHEN[Col A]<0 THEN [Col A]*-1 ELSE [Col A] END))),1)) * 
(CASE (SUM(CASE WHEN [Col A] < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) %2) WHEN 1 THEN -1 WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) AS [Col A Multi]
FROM yourtable
```

Example Input:

```
1
2
3
-4
```

Output:

```
Col A Multi
-24
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01ddc/3/0

Comment: @Alex Sure, what don't you feel is clearly explained?

Comment: what is exp? and explanation of the equation

Comment: My Math skills obviously need some improvement. Nice answer!

Comment: Brilliant answer. Higher mathematics rules!

Comment: @SQLPolice Thanks! I am quite proud of this one !

Comment: what if the cols contain a value as zero

Comment: @KishanKumar updated answer to deal with "An invalid floating point operation occurred." (When you have a 0 in your data).

Comment: @Matt now its ok. But i would like to get an answer of 0 when the [col A] = 0

Comment: @Matt I am sorry but when you have 0 the result should be 0. Not null or anything else but 0. Most of time if you have a 0 in your set of data for this kind of operation it is most of time a data input error (I agree). But that's another story.

Comment: @MarcoGuignard with regards to only having 0 i would leave it open to how the end user would want to resolve this depending on their other data, something as basic as wrapping it all in a `CASE` and saying when result is `NULL` then `0` OR putting a `CASE` inside the calculation (with the possibility of needing to `GROUP` data.

Comment: Nice answer, but did you consider negative numbers where LOG doesn't work? in that case you should use ABS function to calculate the magnitude and then compute the sign of product

Comment: @Alireza I did not, but i have now, added an extra answer (and sql fiddle) to deal with negative numbers.

Comment: For the countless people trying to apply this expression to SQLite with endless grief, you need to change `LOG` to `LN` to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL you could use

```
select max(sum)
from 
(
  select @sum := @sum * colA as sum 
  from your_table
  cross join (select @sum := 1) s
) tmp
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25937/1)

Answer (score 3):

This is a complicated matter.  If you want to take signs and handle zero, the expression is a bit complicated:

```
select (case when sum(case when a = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 0
             else exp(sum(log(abs(a)))) *
                  (case when sum(case when a < 0 then 1 else 0 end) % 2 = 1 then -1 else 1 end)
        end) as ProductA
from table t;
```

Note:  you do not specify a database.  In some databases you would use `LN()` rather than `LOG()`.  Also the function for the modulo operator (to handle negative values) also differs by database.

Comment: @Matt . . . First, that is dependent on the database, but not surprising.  If the OP knows the values are integers, then s/he can round the value.  If an integer is *not* expected, then  23.999999999999993 is close enough to 24 for any purpose I can think of.

Comment: wasn't questioning your logic and 23.999999.... is close enough for most purposes.

Comment: @Matt . . . Your assumption that the values are integers is reasonable, based on the question, but it is not explicitly stated in the question.

Comment: absolutely, however like most questions from new users, we will most likely never find out!

Answer (score 2):

You can do It simply by declaring an variable in following, [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) is used to avoid `NULLS`.

```
DECLARE @var INT

SELECT @var = Col1 * COALESCE(@var, 1) FROM Tbl

SELECT @var
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bfee1/2)**

Comment: Very elegant. But instead of mucking about with `COALESCE` and confusing the whole issue: why don't you simply initialise `@var = 1` before the `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 2):

A quick example, supposing that the column contains only two values: *a* and *b*, both different than zero.

We are interested `in x = a*b`.
Then, applying some math, we have:

```
x = a * b -> log(x) = log(a * b) -> log(x) = log(a) + log(b) ->
exp[log(x)] =  exp[log(a) + log(b)] -> x = exp[log(a) + log(b)].
```

Therefore:

```
a * b = exp[log(a) + log(b)]
```

This explains Matt's answer:

> SELECT ROUND(EXP(SUM(LOG([Col A]))),1)
>
> FROM your table

ROUND is required because of the limited precision of the SQL variables.