# Snowflake: How do I multiple a column of binaries (cast as integers)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Lets say I have table with 1 column like this:

```
Col A
1
0
0
1
```

If I SUM it, then I will get this:

```
Col A
2
```

My question is: how do I multiply Col A so I get the following?

Col A
0

I found a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665719/how-to-multiply-all-values-within-a-column-with-sql-like-sum) but not one that works for a list of 1s and 0s because it's using the log() function:

```
SELECT ROUND(EXP(SUM(LOG([Col A]))),1)
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Perhaps use a case expression. If the column contains a zero, then zero, else the solution from that other answer.

Comment: That's algebraically the same as `MIN([Col A])`

Comment: @MatBailie For 0 and 1 MIN is the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the A column really only contains 0 and 1, then we can simply check for the presence of at least one 0.  If found, the product is 0, otherwise it is 1.

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN [Col A] = 0 THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS product
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: If it really is only 0 or 1, the product is equal to the min?

Answer (score 0):

If allowed values are only 0 and 1 then [BITAND_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/bitand_agg) could be used:

> Returns the bitwise AND value of all non-NULL numeric records in a group.
>
> For each bit position, if all rows have the bit set to 1, then the bit is set to 1 in the result. If any rows have that bit set to zero, the result is zero.

```
SELECT BITAND_AGG(colA)
FROM tab;
```